# Why am I getting 'appletviewer not found' error?

Tags: java, applet, awt, appletviewer

**I have written a program `appletExample.java`.**

```
c:/users/set path = "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16\bin"
c:/users/desktop/jp>appletviewer appletexample.java
```

The error is"

```
'applet viewer' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.
```

I am getting this error. But set path is also correct way but why this error has occurred? Could anyone explain to me?

Comment: Because applets have been dead for years.

Comment: browsers stopped supporting applets years ago, probably they 've been (starting to) removing them from the language.

Comment: @Stultuske but i used them in command prompt only

Comment: @CR28 so? if it is removed from the language, do you think it'll magically work because you called it in the command prompt?

Answer (score 1):

I think **jdk 16 has eliminated applets** so one who would like to run applets download **jdk 8 version.**

As jdk 15 also doesn't have applets if you want to check your version support appletviewer or not do this thing:
Go to **windows> program files >java > jdk 1.5.05 > bin**

So in that folder if you find **appletviewer.exe** then your version supports applets.

If you don't find that thing then you must go and **download jdk 8** version or others which support applets.

Answer (score 0):

As other people have said, applets are history really but try the following:

```
(cd to wherever appletexample.java is)
set PATH="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16\bin";%PATH%
appletviewer appletexample.java
```

Bear in mind that to run a *java* file as an argument to appletviewer, it needs to have a special format with commented-out applet tags in the Java source

Comment: I think jdk 16 doesn't have applets or appletviewer

Comment: I think jdk 16 has eliminated applets  so one who would like to run applets download jdk 8 version.

Comment: Ah yes, you could be right. I have 16 installed but I see appletviewer points to a version 8 JDK and my 16 has no appletviewer. Applets are a dead end